# Google search box on kentico

Tags: google-search, kentico

We have a website built in Kentico CMS but we are not happy with the results of its website search facility. We would like to replace the Kentico search with Google site-search box.

Is there any way of doing it without Google displaying Google Adds on the website search results?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is a Kentico related question, it's more a Google related question.  I'd check out the [Google Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/) service/tool from Google.  This would get you what you're looking for.  If you want ad free, that's an annual fee of $100 (as of this post date).

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.